# Arduino-Trying to calculate a neural network

Tags: matlab, arduino, neural-network

I'm trying to calculate a neural network with this code below

```
#include <math.h> 
double feat_hid[10]; 
double output[4]; 

const double w_hid[8][10] = 
{ 
    {0.0706307913427445,-0.332136075169963,1.86159334821608,1.55009706502897,1.55669357055137,-1.93539022266504,1.40698067828037,-0.196054693169832,-0.317952257631136,4.69951344792126}, 
    {-0.860303689780744,-0.142965971622307,1.00938809624265,3.03147950247308,0.26570362705432,-0.63835074899079,-0.108472152405573,-0.465092677563643,-1.26640787415541,3.47897119519849}, 
    {-0.272080445746987,0.388264886856488,1.93120693933139,2.63260374630115,-0.403646834510117,-1.69806363784962,-1.47457233648421,-1.50775491078107,-0.835555146571103,0.586017106027158}, 
    {0.523268479966795,1.60528083325264,1.8945332979293,2.83572254589689,-1.68716858062427,-0.575246483351286,0.408066044886574,0.58303163597391,1.27390651063673,0.00318251321831592}, 
    {0.363035740315566,-0.696513924175445,1.41563086072654,1.42184591641306,2.04584849389715,0.528929786530872,1.07312589674496,0.309695239536318,1.25983320795077,0.522937576790264}, 
    {1.91097305183671,0.526449978690799,-0.00374666478341612,-0.783150846208907,1.01286141219052,-1.60758427665251,-0.040595792623655,-0.751738504583724,-0.930564482543811,-0.0312598878148829}, 
    {-0.364318798326876,6.0862613777679,-1.97910374691563,-0.990892711032243,-4.01625281770135,-0.730723605319977,2.79951479383628,1.23870829231029,-1.96949038202552,-1.48674789633524}, 
    {-2.51147997247322,-2.42006923324837,0.0825476300769622,0.780436871112016,-0.151841195266197,0.3603578344112,-1.10038496139283,1.01784327038377,-2.33380006889957,-0.276962857144392} 
}; 

const double w_out[11][4] = 
{ 
    {-0.848153262003428,1.04206942072723,-0.56827515726385,0.368049168481758}, 
    {2.65699122475564,-2.31195040158215,-0.324512289348535,-0.0248140339246439}, 
    {0.819329194280546,0.039943623410223,-1.25202766689859,0.393685637397724}, 
    {-1.28944659517956,2.66620424439295,-0.968011825082177,-0.404502491304304}, 
    {-0.224432096177094,-0.239370531739619,1.95124987383465,-1.47584887746872}, 
    {0.520195254302156,-0.0716719005040372,-0.795815587506882,0.344121703272989}, 
    {-1.260329779349,2.04221311676928,0.251086051743563,-1.03192351329109}, 
    {-0.680299559455324,0.452665873842875,-0.457043098095797,0.699247978937067}, 
    {0.262467710721102,0.876119011755995,-1.84541649804428,0.689973715895836}, 
    {0.602141912445942,-2.3913813206841,1.43782014708464,0.346066727829377}, 
    {-0.0789595649460575,0.0759034703177117,-0.954465934396254,-1.06633481363805} 
}; 
double accum; 
double feature[7] = { 0.802748046,  0.79983412  ,-0.379610559,  0.02006534, 0.244444444 -1, 0.872340426}; 

void setup() 
{ 
    /* add setup code here */ 
    Serial.begin(9600); 
}   

void loop() 
{ 
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
    { 
        accum =0; 
        accum = w_hid[7][i]; 

        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) 
        { 
            accum += feature[j] * w_hid[j][i]; 
        }   
        //Serial.println(accum,4); 

        feat_hid[i] = tanh(accum); 
    }   

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
    { 
        accum=0; 
        accum = w_hid[10][i]; 
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) 
        { 
            accum += feat_hid[j] * w_out[j][i]; 
        }   
        output[i] = (accum); 
    }   

    Serial.println("wew"); 
    Serial.println(output[0], 7); 
    Serial.println(output[1], 7); 
    Serial.println(output[2], 7); 
    Serial.println(output[3], 7); 

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
    { 
        feat_hid[i] = 0; 
    }   
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
    { 
        output[i] = 0; 
    } 
}
```

The output goes by these value :

-2.0422704

-0.2195258

3.6133847

-1.3158617

but when I try to recalculate with matlab, the output goes by (this is the right one):

0.856575444075245

-0.997328999300809

-0.911066976760467

-0.949747387652545

My question is,
is there something wrong with arduino and floating/double calculation which makes the calculation get wrong result? As I recall, the code between the sketch above and the matlab code is similiar.

Thanks for any feed back~

Comment: if you are wondering about data being truncated and so on throughout your calculations, just use Serial.println as you perform your calculations to see where your problem is.

Comment: @JoshEngelsma alright, I've tried that from the first time the calculation runs, and it's already wrong (as I recall), maybe the the calling of the array is wrong? Thanks for the comment~

Comment: I have build your prog on my PC and I got the same results as your arduino. The problem is not an arduino one. Are you sure your code is correct ?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @oreljul, i've already got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

double feature[7] = { 0.802748046,  0.79983412  ,-0.379610559,  0.02006534, **0.244444444 -1**, 0.872340426};

Didn't you forget a comma between those 2 values?

(sorry to post this as an answer, still can't comment here)

Comment: It was indeed the problem?